# Oracle APEX, PL/SQL pkg or prc to join multiple tables to extract data and download it as a flat file based on page item value

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I'm using Oracle APEX api, `apex_data_export.export` on a button click to download output of sql query as a flat file by passing sql query by joining multiple tables and passing page items in where clause for `p_sql_query` parameter. Since the table data has millions of records, api is either taking more time to process the output and to download the file or it is resulting in timeout error.

Hence would like to know if there is any alternate method to achieve this thru custom pl/sql process either by creating a package or a procedure. Appreciate any help on this.

Thanks,
Richa

Comment: For an average query, how many rows are you exporting?

Answer (score 1):

Apex wouldn't be my first choice to load *millions of rows* into Oracle. I'd use SQL*Loader. That utility is really, really fast.

Read about it in Oracle documentation related to your database version (though, most basic functionalities didn't change much over the years). This is [19c version](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sutil/oracle-sql-loader.html#GUID-8D037494-07FA-4226-B507-E1B2ED10C144).

Basically, you'd

- create control file (which *instructs* the utility which file to import and how)
- execute it from the operating system command line

  - how to do that from Oracle? One option is to create a stored procedure which is then invoked by DBMS_SCHEDULER built-in package
- once data is loaded into the target table, you have all time you need to parse it with PL/SQL program you'll write (a stored procedure, most probably) and do whatever you want to do

---

**[EDIT]** Actually, it turns out that you want to *export* data, not *import*. I have no idea what made me think differently; but, if you ever wanted to hear my opinion about *importing* you've just got it :)

As of exporting: I'd suggest you to write a **stored procedure** which utilizes built-in `UTL_FILE` package and create file by using its capabilities. Drawback is that it'll be created in a folder which (most probably) resides on a database server, so you'll have to talk to DBA to create it, create Oracle directory, grant read/write privileges to user who will be using it and **then** you'll be able to use it. Read: create an export file.

What's good about it? It is a PL/SQL program unit, and it lets you do various things - not only join any number of tables, but also perform certain calculations (if you have to) and - once you have everything ready - put a line into the resulting file (and here we come to another drawback: you'll do it line-by-line).

But, it won't cost much to try it. DBA can do their part of the job in a minute or two. You'll write a procedure in half an hour. Give it a try.

Comment: I believe the question is about downloading, not uploading

Comment: Hi @KoenLostrie, thank you. Hi Littlefoot, the solution you provided is for uploading data to Oracle table. But I'm looking for a solution to download data from different tables say for example 'select * from emp e join dept d on e.dept_id = d.dept where ename in :P1_ENAME'. This is only example and in real time, I have more than 5 tables to join and each table has millions of records. The report I show in APEX is only Emp table but on click of download button, I would like to call procedure which inturn runs query and output the data in xlsx or csv format. Preferred xlsx format.

Comment: Phew, I totally misread the question, bravo :( I apologize.

Comment: I edited the answer; have a look, please.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [zip_util](https://github.com/commi235/APEX_IR_XLSX/tree/master/lib/xlsx_builder/lib#zip_util) which is part of the open source [APEXIR_XLSX](https://github.com/commi235/APEX_IR_XLSX/tree/master) APEX plug-in that can create Excel spreadsheets from an interactive report.  We use that plug-in a lot at work; I've glanced at the code now and then for the zip-util, and I think it can be used by itself to do what you want to do.

Comment: Hi Mark, thank you for reply. Looks like this plugin download the IR and to achieve it, I can use built in Download functionality from Oracle APEX IR attributes section by enabling download option. Since I'm working on big data, I can only display snapshot (few columns with limited rows) of data on IR. However if user click download button, all I want is, to download data that joins multiple table with where clause as page item value. This query can be inside procedure and on click of button I'm looking for a solution that runs this query and download data into excel or csv.